# All php files showing as 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, web-services, apache, .htaccess

**Problem:** Any php file we attempt to access on our website shows up as a 500 internal server error. I'm not sure if this is related but I have had a look in the error logs and the below error appears:

```
    [08-Nov-2013 12:41:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/htscanner.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/htscanner.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

**Attempt:** Some of the things I have tried to do is delete the over size error log and renamed the htaccess file to see if that was causing the problem.

**Page:** You can see the problem at this page: http://science.org.au/support-us/donate-now.html (Half way down in the iframe)

**Question:** Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Things to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [this](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/controlpanels/ispconfig3/solve-error-message-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-htscanner-so/)?

> edit the file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini:
>
> and remove the lines:

```
[htscanner] Extension = “htscanner.so” 
config_file = “.htaccess”
default_docroot = “/var/www”
```

Comment: I shall implement this tomorrow and let you know. Would that be the cause of the internal 500 error?

Comment: In the etc folder there is no php5 folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should pay more attention to what your error log says. According to it, you should either install [`htscanner.so`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.htscanner.php) PHP extension, or remove reference to it from your [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php).

Comment: Hard to speculate, but most likely accessing your 404 page leads to recursive loading of htscanner, which... you should be thankful that Apache breaks that infinite loop